# parse .csv data into matrix or 2 dimensional array bash/shell awk

Tags: bash, shell, matrix, multidimensional-array, awk

I have a coma delimited csv file named 'itrs.csv' which I want to parse into a matrix or 2d array using a script bash or shell

```
Loads\PostDate,schedule,seta,eeta,2019-11-05,2019-11-06,2019-11-07,2019-11-08
BANAMEX,7,1:18:10,1:23:45,G,G,C,C
EMEA,5,0:21:00,1:01:00,G,G,G,C
```

I have tried the following:

```
declare -A matrix
eval matrix=($(awk -f, itrs.csv))
for ((i=0;i<=2;i++))
do
    for ((j=0;j<=$6;j++))
    do
    echo ${matrix[$i,$j]}" " 
    done
    echo
done
```

but above code is throwing errors. I also would like to know how to check the number of columns and rows while parsing data because csv file size may change.

Comment: *but above code is throwing errors* And what are those errors?

Comment: awk: cmd. line:1: itrs.csv
awk: cmd. line:1:     ^ syntax error

Comment: Take a look at the awk man page and then think about what `-f,` means. Also see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for some of the problems with your approach.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can do this: Create an associative array, iterate over lines and keep the count of the current line, then iterate over the fields and create an associative array with indexes as requested.

```
i=0
declare -A matrix
while IFS=, read -r -a line; do
   for ((j = 0; j < ${#line[@]}; ++j)); do
        matrix[$i,$j]=${line[$j]}
    done
    ((i++))
done < itrs.csv
```

After it `declare -p matrix` would output:

```
declare -A matrix=([1,5]="G" [1,4]="G" [1,7]="C" [1,6]="C" [1,1]="7" [1,0]="BANAMEX" [1,3]="1:23:45" [1,2]="1:18:10" [0,4]="2019-11-05" [0,5]="2019-11-06" [0,6]="2019-11-07"[0,7]="2019-11-08" [0,0]="Loads\\PostDate" [0,1]="schedule" [0,2]="seta" [0,3]="eeta" [2,6]="G" [2,7]="C" [2,4]="G"[2,5]="G" [2,2]="0:21:00" [2,3]="1:01:00" [2,0]="EMEA" [2,1]="5" )
```

- See [bashfaq How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)
- Don't use `eval`. `eval` is evil. Don't `eval arr=($(..))` unless you know what you are doing. In your case, using `eval` looks like it has little to zero sense.
- The error comes from `awk`. `awk` works like `awk [options] script [file]`, you could `awk -F, '{print $0}' itrs.csv`, but it would make no sense. The `itrs.csv` is parsed by `awk` as being the script - as it makes no sense as a `awk` script, the tool throws an error.
- To read for example the *first line only* separated by comma into an array in bash you can `IFS=, line=($(head -n1 itrs.csv))`. The `-F,` affects how `awk` parses the file, not how `bash` creates array - for that use `IFS`.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate your time. So in here, I understand how IFS is working but since I have access to each field within the csv, will I be able to change some fields ${line[$j]} directly in the csv after doing some validations? Or is it just read/printing access?

Comment: I don't understand the question. The `< itrs.csv` opens an input stream, it doesn't output anything, it can't change the file contents. Editing such file would be easy in `awk`, without any associative array in bash. I don't understand if you want to edit the file (which is a different job then reading the file into an associative array...) or you want to edit the associative array like `matrix[2,3]="new_value"`.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear. what I want to do is loop through the fields in the csv file, do some validations and fire sql querries to get status then update csv field. I thought I will be able to achieve that by parsing data from csv to a matrix.

Comment: Cool, so now with my code you have an associative array of the values from the file. You can now write a serialization function - you can write from the associative array back to your file. Just iterate over the indexes in proper order, output array elements and insert `,` where you need to and newlines where you need to. Tip: `printf "%s\n" "${!matrix[@]}" | sort -n` seems to generate the indexes in proper order.

Comment: @Elcappoo what you want to do is fine but you'd never use a shell for that, you'd just do it in awk or some other text processing tool. See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: I am not very familiar with awk. Initially started with awk, but while looping through the fields, I still need to access the file header column to calculate time difference. I tried storing it in an array outside the awk function. But then I couldnt access it from inside awk.

Comment: Ask a question if you'd like help with that and I'm sure someone will be able to help you. Make sure to provide a [mcve] in your question which includes concise, testable sample in[put and expected output.